# Sony Vegas Transition Effect and Colour Correction

Tags: vegas-pro

Can you please help me with this issue here?
When I apply some transition effect to my videos colour correction gets mixed up and from something good looking I get a video with blue colour over it.

See the pictures so you can know what am I talking about.

By the way, I'm working in Sony Vegas Pro 17, and there are no colours added to the effect (transition) I am using.

[image]

[image]